# Statistical criteria for signal registration

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I want to find statistical criteria for signal registration (see picts). When I don't have a signal I have a simple gaussian two-dimenshial distribution. When I have a signal I have gaussian plus some long "tail". Direction of a "tail" may differs, but I have some minimum length of a tail for a proper signal.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

So the question is how can I prove that my distribution is far enough from plain gaussian? It looks like it is a common problem in statistic but I haven't found any useful examples of such a problem.

I've tried to use $\chi^2$ criteria but it didn't worked out --- $p$-value for my signal was always 1.0. What kind of criteria can I use in my case?

Here is the data:

Plain gaussian:

```
[[ 0.    0.    0.    0.01  0.01  0.02  0.02  0.02  0.01  0.01  0.    0.    0.  ]
 [ 0.    0.    0.01  0.02  0.04  0.06  0.06  0.06  0.04  0.02  0.01  0.    0.  ]
 [ 0.    0.01  0.03  0.06  0.11  0.15  0.17  0.15  0.11  0.06  0.03  0.01  0.  ]
 [ 0.01  0.02  0.06  0.14  0.24  0.33  0.37  0.33  0.24  0.14  0.06  0.02  0.01]
 [ 0.01  0.04  0.11  0.24  0.41  0.57  0.64  0.57  0.41  0.24  0.11  0.04  0.01]
 [ 0.02  0.06  0.15  0.33  0.57  0.8   0.9   0.8   0.57  0.33  0.15  0.06  0.02]
 [ 0.02  0.06  0.17  0.37  0.64  0.9   1.    0.9   0.64  0.37  0.17  0.06  0.02]
 [ 0.02  0.06  0.15  0.33  0.57  0.8   0.9   0.8   0.57  0.33  0.15  0.06  0.02]
 [ 0.01  0.04  0.11  0.24  0.41  0.57  0.64  0.57  0.41  0.24  0.11  0.04  0.01]
 [ 0.01  0.02  0.06  0.14  0.24  0.33  0.37  0.33  0.24  0.14  0.06  0.02  0.01]
 [ 0.    0.01  0.03  0.06  0.11  0.15  0.17  0.15  0.11  0.06  0.03  0.01  0.  ]
 [ 0.    0.    0.01  0.02  0.04  0.06  0.06  0.06  0.04  0.02  0.01  0.    0.  ]
 [ 0.    0.    0.    0.01  0.01  0.02  0.02  0.02  0.01  0.01  0.    0.    0.  ]]
```

Still not a signal:

```
[[ 0.    0.    0.    0.01  0.01  0.01  0.02  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.    0.    0.  ]
 [ 0.    0.    0.01  0.02  0.03  0.05  0.05  0.05  0.03  0.02  0.01  0.    0.  ]
 [ 0.    0.01  0.02  0.05  0.09  0.13  0.14  0.13  0.09  0.05  0.02  0.01  0.  ]
 [ 0.01  0.02  0.05  0.11  0.2   0.27  0.31  0.28  0.2   0.11  0.05  0.02  0.01]
 [ 0.01  0.03  0.09  0.2   0.34  0.48  0.56  0.52  0.37  0.21  0.1   0.03  0.01]
 [ 0.01  0.05  0.13  0.27  0.48  0.69  0.84  0.83  0.62  0.4   0.22  0.07  0.01]
 [ 0.02  0.05  0.14  0.31  0.54  0.78  0.99  1.    0.77  0.56  0.39  0.11  0.02]
 [ 0.01  0.05  0.13  0.27  0.48  0.69  0.84  0.83  0.62  0.4   0.22  0.07  0.01]
 [ 0.01  0.03  0.09  0.2   0.34  0.48  0.56  0.52  0.37  0.21  0.1   0.03  0.01]
 [ 0.01  0.02  0.05  0.11  0.2   0.27  0.31  0.28  0.2   0.11  0.05  0.02  0.01]
 [ 0.    0.01  0.02  0.05  0.09  0.13  0.14  0.13  0.09  0.05  0.02  0.01  0.  ]
 [ 0.    0.    0.01  0.02  0.03  0.05  0.05  0.05  0.03  0.02  0.01  0.    0.  ]
 [ 0.    0.    0.    0.01  0.01  0.01  0.02  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.    0.    0.  ]]
```

A signal:

```
[[ 0.    0.    0.    0.01  0.01  0.01  0.02  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.    0.    0.  ]
 [ 0.    0.    0.01  0.02  0.03  0.05  0.05  0.05  0.03  0.02  0.01  0.    0.  ]
 [ 0.    0.01  0.02  0.05  0.09  0.13  0.14  0.13  0.09  0.05  0.02  0.01  0.  ]
 [ 0.01  0.02  0.05  0.11  0.2   0.27  0.31  0.28  0.2   0.11  0.05  0.02  0.01]
 [ 0.01  0.03  0.09  0.2   0.34  0.48  0.56  0.52  0.37  0.21  0.1   0.03  0.01]
 [ 0.01  0.05  0.13  0.27  0.48  0.69  0.84  0.83  0.62  0.4   0.22  0.08  0.03]
 [ 0.02  0.05  0.14  0.31  0.54  0.78  0.99  1.    0.77  0.56  0.4   0.29  0.19]
 [ 0.01  0.05  0.13  0.27  0.48  0.69  0.84  0.83  0.62  0.4   0.22  0.08  0.03]
 [ 0.01  0.03  0.09  0.2   0.34  0.48  0.56  0.52  0.37  0.21  0.1   0.03  0.01]
 [ 0.01  0.02  0.05  0.11  0.2   0.27  0.31  0.28  0.2   0.11  0.05  0.02  0.01]
 [ 0.    0.01  0.02  0.05  0.09  0.13  0.14  0.13  0.09  0.05  0.02  0.01  0.  ]
 [ 0.    0.    0.01  0.02  0.03  0.05  0.05  0.05  0.03  0.02  0.01  0.    0.  ]
 [ 0.    0.    0.    0.01  0.01  0.01  0.02  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.    0.    0.  ]]
```

A signal:

```
[[ 0.07  0.12  0.1   0.06  0.03  0.02  0.02  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.    0.    0.  ]
 [ 0.12  0.24  0.27  0.19  0.12  0.08  0.06  0.05  0.03  0.02  0.01  0.    0.  ]
 [ 0.1   0.27  0.41  0.4   0.33  0.25  0.19  0.14  0.09  0.05  0.02  0.01  0.  ]
 [ 0.06  0.19  0.4   0.56  0.6   0.54  0.43  0.31  0.2   0.11  0.05  0.02  0.01]
 [ 0.03  0.12  0.33  0.6   0.81  0.84  0.73  0.55  0.36  0.19  0.09  0.03  0.01]
 [ 0.02  0.08  0.25  0.54  0.84  1.    0.95  0.74  0.49  0.27  0.12  0.05  0.01]
 [ 0.02  0.06  0.19  0.43  0.73  0.95  0.96  0.79  0.54  0.3   0.14  0.05  0.01]
 [ 0.01  0.05  0.14  0.31  0.55  0.74  0.79  0.68  0.47  0.27  0.12  0.04  0.01]
 [ 0.01  0.03  0.09  0.2   0.36  0.49  0.54  0.47  0.33  0.19  0.09  0.03  0.01]
 [ 0.01  0.02  0.05  0.11  0.19  0.27  0.3   0.27  0.19  0.11  0.05  0.02  0.01]
 [ 0.    0.01  0.02  0.05  0.09  0.12  0.14  0.12  0.09  0.05  0.02  0.01  0.  ]
 [ 0.    0.    0.01  0.02  0.03  0.05  0.05  0.04  0.03  0.02  0.01  0.    0.  ]
 [ 0.    0.    0.    0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.    0.    0.  ]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know much about signal processing and even less about the problem, but to me it looks like a classification problem. I would try to extract some features from the data, and then apply usual models like logistic regression that would allow to get some statistics and their p-values.

Although it's quite hard to do it with just 4 training examples, I'll try. I hope my findings should generalize to more data.

First of all, I would extract the direction of the tail and then rotate the image. The simplest way I could think of is to use PCA. For 2-dimensional data PCA will output a 2-dimensional rotation matrix $\begin{bmatrix} \cos \theta & - \sin \theta \\ \sin \theta & \cos \theta \end{bmatrix}$, so once we learn $\theta$ we can rotate the image.

[image]

Once the data is rotated, since the image is symmetric we can sum $y$ out. We also can subtract the first no-signal image from the rest and then fourier-transform each:

[image]

We see that amplitudes of 1st and 3rd frequency components may be helpful in distinguishing signal from no signal. Eventually we can use all of them, but since we have only 4 training examples, it should be sufficient.

Indeed, it looks quite possible to separate these two classes:

[image]

Here I don't include the first training example, because it's 0 everywhere and FFT of 0-vector is `NaN`. So on these features it should be possible to use logistic regression or some other classification model.

An IPython notebook with all the code is available [here](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/alexeygrigorev/notebooks/blob/master/answers/signal-detection.ipynb). But if something happens with the link, here's a method that extracts the features:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import ndimage
import pandas as pd

def extract_features(img, th, base):
    df = pd.DataFrame(img)
    stacked = pd.DataFrame(df.stack())
    stacked.reset_index(inplace=True)
    stacked.columns = ('y', 'x', 'v')
    filtered = stacked[stacked.v >= th]
    X = filtered[['x', 'y']].values
    X_cent = X - X.mean(axis=0)
    _, _, V = np.linalg.svd(X_cent)
    v = V[0, :]

    deg = 180 * np.arccos(v[0]) / np.pi

    if abs(deg) > 1e-6:
        X_rot = ndimage.rotate(img, deg, reshape=False)
    else:
        X_rot = img

    s = X_rot.sum(axis=0) - base
    f = np.fft.fft(s)
    fabs = np.abs(np.fft.fftshift(f))
    fabs = fabs / fabs.max()
    return fabs[[6, 8]]

base = X1.sum(axis=0) # X1 is the "no-signal" image
f2 = extract_features(X2, 0.25, base)
```

For comments, please refer to the notebook.

References:

- PCA for rotating images http://staff.ustc.edu.cn/~zwp/teach/MVA/pcaimg.pdf

Comment: How exactly would you apply logistic regression to these data?

Comment: Thank you for answer. It looks quite complicated without code example. If you provide a code it would be esier for me to understand this method.

Comment: The biggest question is how can I get \theta to rotate my image?

Comment: I added a link to an ipython notebook with the code

Comment: @AlexeyGrigorev great answer - if I could I would give you more than +1 for it! Could you however post the crucial parts of the code (of formulas you used etc.) as a part of your answer..? Consider that for some reason your link could stop working and then a great part of your answer will disappear so others would not be possibler to benefit from it.

Comment: done! I hope this is enough

Comment: I see. Thank you for explonation. Now it's clear for me. It still seems overcomplicated but I belive I can work it out.